# mono does not port macOS cocoa 100% correctly

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I try to use Visual Studio macOS to develop a macOS app using c# language.

but I found that there so many bugs in mono

for example:

UITabView has property  'numberOfTabViewItems' 'tabViewItemAtIndex', but in VS macOS it reported error.

NSTabView

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstabview?language=objc

```
using System;
using AppKit;
using Foundation;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

[image]

[image]

your comment welcome

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of chitchat on "VS for MacOS is the bestest evar"? Could you please [edit] post to clarify what exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin normalizes macOS/iOS API names to a C# style naming:

So ObjC `numberOfTabViewItems` becomes just `Items`

Xamarin's NSTabView Class : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nstabview?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14